# How to set Java classpath in bash script used in Ubuntu and Windows (Cygwin)

Tags: java, bash, cygwin, classpath

I am writing a bash script that should execute some Java application that needs a specific classpath.

Further, this script should be executable on both, Ubuntu & Windows (Cygwin).

**The problem:** The seperator on Windows is "**;**" and the seperator on Ubuntu is "**:**". This results in `java -cp A.jar;B.jar Main` on Windows (also when using cygwin, because it's using Windows' java) and `java -cp A.jar:B.jar Main` on Ubuntu.

**The question:** How to detect in the bash script which underlying operating system is running / which java classpath seperator to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A naive (but quick to implement) approach: run `uname -a` first and push that into a variable. Then check if that output contains "Ubuntu".

If so, you should be using the ":" as separator; otherwise ";" should do.

And if you want to be prepared for other platforms in the future; instead of doing a simple if/else; you might want to check what `uname -a` has to say on cygwin; to setup some `$SEPARATOR_CHAR` variable using a bash [switch](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html) statement.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with `uname`. Since it should also be able to run on Mac (and probably later other *nix), I think it would be best to check what cygwin says. Then I could use ":" as default, while just switching to ";" when `uname` matches cygwin's (Windows) name

Comment: I'll just let this question open for some more time, probably more answers will come. If not, this will become the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide the final solution:

I just tested `uname -s` on Ubuntu, Mac, and Windows running cygwin and came up with following script:

```
if [ "$(uname)" == "Darwin" ]; then
    # Do something under Mac OS X platform
    SEP=":"
elif [ "$(expr substr $(uname -s) 1 5)" == "Linux" ]; then
    # Do something under GNU/Linux platform
    SEP=":"
elif [ "$(expr substr $(uname -s) 1 6)" == "CYGWIN" ]; then
    # Do something under Windows NT platform
    SEP=";"
fi
```